# process result and display in same page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to know how to post data from a page and Display the result in the same page? I have a controller with the following code: I have created a seperate view "Result" which finally directing to Index.

```
//EmployeeController.cs
public ActionResult Index  (List<Employee> employees = null)  
{
    employees = employees == null 
        ? db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).ToList() 
        : employees;

     return View(employees);                 
} 

public ActionResult Result(Employee employee, decimal minsal,decimal maxsal)
{
    var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
    employees = db.Employees
        .Where(p => p.DepartmentID == employee.DepartmentID  
             && p.Salary > minsal && p.Salary < maxsal);

    var empList = employees.ToList();

    ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DeptName",  employee.DepartmentID);

        return View("Index", empList);          
    }
```

View: (Result.cshtml)

```
@model _4th_assignment.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
}

<h2>Result</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Select Department:  @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", "--select--")
    </p>
    <p>
        Enter Salary  Range:  Min @Html.TextBox("minsal")     Max     
        @Html.TextBox("maxsal")
    </p>
    <p>  <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
}
```

I have created a link in the index page "filter the employees with salary range and department". When i click on this link it goes to the Result page and then the filtered results are displayed in the Index page.

View: (index.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<_4th_assignment.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("filter the employees with salary range and department ", "Result")
 </p>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.DeptName)
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DeptName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmployeeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmployeeID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

Now what i want to do is if i click on the link "filter the employees with salary range and department" in the index page it shuold ask for the inputs in the index page and the result also should be displayed in the index page only.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this can be,
return partialview() instead of view() from the Result action.
make the result.cshtml, a partialview.
put this partialview in the index.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You need roughly 4 modifications.

1. Create an `_IndexPartial.cshtml` partial view specifically for the result view unless you do want an Index View that uses the layout? (Same as Index.cshtml w/out layout)
2. Create an ActionResult that returns this partial view with the `IEnumerable<_4th_assignment.Models.Employee` List.

   ```
   public ActionResult GetEmployees(int deptId)
   {
       var employees = from a in db.Employees
                      select a;
       employees = employees.Where(a => a.DeptId.Equals(deptId));

       //... code here

       return PartialView("_IndexPartial", employees); 
   }
   ```
3. Create an empty div in the Result View

   ie: `<div id="employee-list"></div>`
4. Change **Html.BeginForm** to **Ajax.BeginForm** like this:

   @using(Ajax.BeginForm("GetEmployees", "Controller", new AjaxOptions()
    {

   ```
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   UpdateTargetId = "employee-list",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
   ```

   }))

NOTE: The UpdateTargetId is an AJAX callback