# MVC 5 button click event that updates a label on the same form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5, is it possible to have a button click event that updates a label on the same page?

For example, if I have a structure

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("textbox1")
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.Label("label1")
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Clicking the `Submit` button grabs the `textbox1`'s value, modifies it according to the function that gets called when the submit button is clicked and then update the value of the label as the result?

Assuming my controller is called `TestController.cs` and this is all done on the `Index` page

I noticed some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007827/process-result-and-display-in-same-page-asp-net-mvc) include using AJAX (new to me)

Answer (score 2):

You don't *necessarily* need to use AJAX for this. All you need to do is pass the value of your label back down as part of your action result e.g.

**Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string label)
    {
        // pass label value into view
        return View("Index", label ?? "");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string textValue)
    {
        // do something with textValue
        // redirect to our Index action passing the new label value
        return RedirectToAction("Index", textValue);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model string

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Form</legend>
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("textbox1")
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.Label("label", Model)
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The benefit of this approach is it follows the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern so if you refreshed the page it wouldn't try to re-submit the form again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

your cshtml code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox"/>
        </p>
        <p>
           <lable id ="lable"></lable>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
document.getElementById("lable").innerHTML = $("#textbox").val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/mgGj6/2/

Hopefully it works...!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with Ajax by using

```
@Ajax.BeginForm();
```

helper. It would be more comfortable for end user.