# Edit and Update a div text

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to edit the text in div and then show the updated data back even on refresh.

Now how do i update it in model.

I guess i am doing something wrong in Model,so please help .Thanks for help :)

Comment: i THINK YOU MENTIONED a method instead of your model

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Where??

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Yaa correct,that is method i am using to update

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee please do not dump code into comments.

Comment: Try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979713/mvc-5-button-click-event-that-updates-a-label-on-the-same-form/24114300#24114300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from the method you call in your model. The value for viewModel hasn't been set because you are just calling a void method.

**Model**

```
public string EditSectionItem(Guid sectionId, string sectionName)
    {
        string name = "Bob";
        DesignerSection section = Sections.Where(s => s.Id == sectionId).FirstOrDefault<DesignerSection>();
        DesignerSection itemToEdit = Sections.Where(n => n.Name == sectionName).FirstOrDefault<DesignerSection>();
        section.Name.Equals(section.Name);
        return name;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public void OnEditDesignerSection(Guid sectionId, string sectionName)
    {
        DesignerAssitModel viewModel = GetModelIntance();
        string name = viewModel.EditSectionItem(sectionId, sectionName);

        HttpContext.Application["DesignerAssit"] = name; // Sets HttpContext.Application["DesignerAssit"] to 'Bob'
    }
```

Do your updates in your model and then return the expected result back to your controller to display the new value in the View.